# Stop on exception on debug in Express version

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express

I use. VS 2013 Express for web When debugging, I need to stop automatically on exceptions.
I call WebApi from Javascript.
I try to follow this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx#AddExceptionsCommand It says I need to add Exceptions command to the Debug menu

1. On the Tools menu, click Customize.
2. The Customize dialog box appears.
3. Click the Commands tab and, in the Menu bar list, click Debug.
4. Click Add Command.
5. In Categories in the Add Command dialog box, click Debug.
6. In Commands, click Exceptions and then click OK.
   But in stage 6, in Commands there is no Exeptions
   Also tried 
   Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General, and uncheck "Just My Code".

Comment: Are you expecting the IDE to "break" on errors thrown in your JAVA code? If so, this cant happen. the Java code runs in your browser, not Server side (which is where your actual .net code is running). You ahve to debug and "break" your java code using your browser. Chrome has nice dev tools built in to do this (F12 in Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting the IDE to "break" on errors thrown in your JAVA code?

If so, this cant happen. the Java code runs in your browser, not Server side (which is where your actual .net code is running).

You have to debug and "break" your java code using your browser. Chrome has nice dev tools built in to do this (F12 in Chrome)

Comment: No. I expect it to stop in Exceptions in WebApi.

Comment: Are you debugging a webAPI project? Or are you debugging a web app using java - connecting to a webAPI?

Comment: I debug WebApi project which contains Html file with Javascript